# Check function while "QF_FD" logic is set throws AccessViolationException

Tags: z3

```
Context lICtx;
Solver lISolver; 

lICtx = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "proof", "true" } });
using (lICtx)
{
    lISolver = lICtx.MkSolver("QF_FD");
    BoolExpr lA = lICtx.MkBoolConst("A");
    lISolver.Assert(lA);
    lISolver.Check();
}
```

If I set the logic to "QF_FD" on the Check function of the solver it will raise error AccessViolationError, this is while if I set the same logic to "All" there is no such error. Can some one help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Z3 does not support proofs for QF_FD. I updated the code to raise a proper exception.